# When slide 5 is displayed change slide transition properties on slide 1

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a presentation that slide 1 .AdvanceOnClick = msoTrue. This is so after the slide show starts, it waits for mouse click before advancing (want slide 1 to display and wait for mouse click).

After the initial mouse click to start advancing, for example on slide 5, I want to change the  .AdvanceOnClick to msoFalse on Slide 1 so the second and subsequent loops auto progress without user intervention. Basically, I want to change the Slide 1 transition properties when the presentation advances to, for example, slide 5.

I have tried the following code, which works fine, but I can't run this code from a different slide;

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).SlideShowTransition
    .AdvanceOnClick = msoTrue
    .AdvanceOnTime = msoTrue
    .AdvanceTime = 5
End With
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Slide 1 has already been shown, so changing any of its properties wouldn't serve any purpose. This sounds like an XY problem to me. What exactly are you trying to do, and why do you think that changing the properties on a slide that has already displayed will do that for you?

Comment: Initially slide 1 will await a mouse click before proceeding to slide 2. After the presentation completes and cycles back to slide 1, I don't want it to wait for a mouse click in the second and subsequent loops. So on the initial run, .AdvanceOnClick  = msoTrue... I want slide 1 to await a mouse click before going to slide 2. After that initial cycle, I want .AdvanceOnClick  = msoFalse so it just loops continuously.  I am trying to have slide 1 display until I mouse click and transition to the other slides. Its a one time thing. The second and other loops I want it to to just loop on its own.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the presentation to loop without the pause after slide 1.
2. Create a separate presentation consisting of only slide 1.
3. Hyperlink that to slide 2 of the looping presentation.

Now slide 1 will display until you click the hyperlink. Once you click, the presentation will loop without stopping. No VBA required.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you. I was thinking driving home from work to make a second presentation with the same first slide, just as you suggested, but I didn't think of having a hyperlink call the looping presentation.......it works great. Thank you so very much...this is a case of 'Don't over complicate it'. Solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one ppt file for some reason then you'll have to use VBA, I believe. This code works just fine only if you use something (a shape) in slide 5 and assign a Mouse Click Action to it to link to slide 1. It doesn't work if you go back to slide 1 using the keyboard arrows or the mouse wheel.

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
    If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = 5 Then 
        With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).SlideShowTransition
            .AdvanceOnClick = msoTrue
            .AdvanceOnTime = msoTrue
            .AdvanceTime = 5
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```